# Can you explain this change of variable in $\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D(0,R)$ be the disc of radius $R>0$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb{C}$, and $dA$ the element of area on the disc. Can you explain the following change of variable?
$$\int_{D(0,R)}\ln|z-w|\,dA(z)=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0} ^{2R}\ln|r|r\,dr\,d\theta? $$
Here, $w$ is a fixed point in the disc.

Comment: Do you mean $\theta=0$ as the lower limit of integration in the first integral on the RHS?

Comment: What happened to $w$?

Comment: This is a real analysis question as you are identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\displaystyle\mathbb{R}^2$. The LHS is $\iint_{|x+iy| \le R} \ln |x+iy - w| dx dy$. The RHS is obtained with the cylindral change of variable $x+iy = r e^{i \theta}, dxdy = r drd\theta$ if $w =0$

Comment: But why $r$ goes from 0 to 2R, and not just R?

Comment: Because you miscopied it

Comment: You mean they misprinted?

Comment: On the RHS, which is the argument of $\ln$: the absolute value $|r|$ or the product $r|r|$?

Comment: And what happened to $w$?

Comment: Chase Ryan Taylor: no, it is $\ln|r|$.